# Javascript object traversal in wrong way

Tags: javascript

I have a json object in occupancy_list as follows :

[image]

I am traversing the object as follows :

```
for(var prop in occupancy_list)
{
     console.log(prop);
}
```

I am getting values in reverse order. Like at first Room 2 then Room 1. How can I fix it ?

Comment: Object properties are not guaranteed to come in any particular order.

Comment: Order is not guaranteed. If you want to guarantee order, use an array.

Comment: [The for...in statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, **in arbitrary order.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: I think this could be the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762402/javascript-for-in-loop-but-in-reverse

Comment: @Tanvir If you can allow ES6, use it. [It](http://www.2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html) makes this possible. (Or even better - the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object.)

Answer (score 0):

Object properties are unsorted and could always be random. If you need order - get the keys, and iterate them that way:

```
Object.keys(occupancy_list).sort(function(a, b) {
   //sort logic
}).forEach(key) {
   //logic on each key
});
```

Comment: *"Object properties are unsorted and could always be random"*. That's not true anymore. For example for properties whose name isn't numeric, the insertion order is used for iterations. See http://www.2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html

Comment: @DenysSéguret -- Which part?

Comment: @DenysSéguret *anymore* - but what about older browsers? I think it'd be safer to assume they're not in order than the opposite.